# Trying to Create Sequential Color Pattern with CSS

Tags: css, design-patterns

I'm trying to create a color pattern that looks something like this https://snipboard.io/po6jrn.jpg that isn't just simply:

```
li:nth-of-type(1) {
   background: blue;
}

li:nth-of-type(2) {
   background: dark-blue;
}

li:nth-of-type(3) {
   background: red;
}

[...]
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to structure the CSS in a way that manages the color pattern automatically for an unknown amount of dynamic elements.

I've been getting close in my tests, but I can't seem to get the color pattern exactly the way I want it. See my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MaxxSkywalker/v0xpub7e/4/

Comment: Probably the best way to do this is using a preprocessor like SASS and utilising colour functions to roll through colours. Maybe this helps, how to do dynamic colours: https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-dynamic-colors-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

So I opted to try and make my life a whole lot easier by adding a fourth color, which forces a diagonal pattern look in a three column grid, utilizing the following technique:

```
li:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
    background-color: orange;
}

li:nth-of-type(4n+2) {
    background-color: green;
}

li:nth-child(4n+3) {
    background: blue;
}

li:nth-child(4n) {
    background: red;
}
```

You can see my results here: https://snipboard.io/Esxlb8.jpg

I would still like to see this effectively done with three colors, but I can settle with this result for now.